# Preload fragment's webview in ViewPager on first run

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview, preload

Ok, so similar questions have been asked, but after trawling SO and google for a day I still can't find an answer to this.

I have a ViewPager loaded with fragments via a pagerAdapter, set up to swipe between the views.

Each fragment has just one WebView

Each webview's html contains a coloured 'body' tag, let's say green.

Also the html contains a full-size image.

When the pages are swiped, the green body of the page is displayed straight away, but there is a flash while the image loads, implying the image is loaded as the page is viewed.

Once the page has been visited then it scrolls to smoothly, with no wait for the image load.

I've tried setOffscreenPageLimit(3) and setOffscreenPageLimit(fragments.size()), but these only have effect on the retention of pages once they've been visited, not on what is loaded at creation time.

Is there any way to pre-load the web pages and their content on creation of the ViewPager and fragments?

Seems strange if there's no answer to this.

Comment: once i had same problem but i didn't get a good solution so i showed the progress dialog while loading of image

Comment: Thanks @Qamar. Was hoping to avoid that by a preload of some kind.

Comment: Actually this worked!!!! webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null); - seems random to me!